# Scroll view doesn't appear in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I got an issue,

This morning i just discovered that i can't see the scrollview and all its contents from the storyboard. In the ViewController Scene, the Scroll view is like transparent, as you can see in the below screen.

[image]
[image]

The app is still working well in the simulator and i have no warnings

Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the scroll view to `hidden`?

Comment: Looks like it is in an other size class.

Comment: @joern no, it's still opaque

Comment: @dasdom, i didn't change anything and from yesterday to this this morning relative to size class. Maybe i missclicked somewhere

Comment: Click the scroll view and check on which size class it is installed.

Comment: thanks, that was it ! It switched to any/any .. Sorry for this dummy question